# ¿Cómo cambiar URL de respuesta en Headers.Location al implementar método POST en Web Api Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Para insertar un Nuevo Cliente en mi WebApi lo hago desde la ruta Controllers/NuevoClienteController.cs mediante un metodo POST, hasta aqui todo bien y el mensaje de respuesta es el siguiente :

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse<NuevoCliente>  (HttpStatusCode.Created,Customer);
 string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = Customer.Id });
                return response;
```

El problema es que la Url de respuesta es algo asi:

```
http://localhost:89067/api/NuevoCliente/ID_Del_NuevoCliente
```

pero yo nesecito que la url en la respuesta sea :

```
http://localhost:89067/api/Cliente/ID_Del_NuevoCliente
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta modificación se hace agregando un `[RoutePrefix("ruta")]` antes del comienzo del Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Cliente")]
public class ApiNuevoCliente
{
```

Luego puedes agregar una Ruta para cada método (GET/POST/DELETE/PUT) agregando el atributo `[Route]` , ejemplo:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("get")] // la ruta te quedaría "api/Cliente/get?Id=10"
public class ApiNuevoCliente Get (int? Id)
{
```

En tu caso este **Route** debe ser `[Route("ID")]` ya que te quedará: `api/Cliente/Id=10`

A su vez debes tener definido en el WebApiConfig.cs las Routes (mapeo).

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();          

   // Web API rutas
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Espero haberte dado una mano.

Un saludo!